# Spring Boot parallel deployment feature

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'd like to know if, for Spring Boot applications deployed as standalone jar files, there is anything resembling the "parallel deployment" feature of Tomcat, where a new version of the app start serving new sessions but the old version of the app still serves already created sessions. Is there any way to replace this feature?

Comment: do you mean something like green/blue deployment strategy?

Comment: If you are using cloud infra you can do anything you want. This isn't a Spring Boot feature but something that you should solve on a different level.